# ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool Access Rule button is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm following the Walkthrough: Managing Web Site Users with Roles.
Everything was successful until I reached the step to add new access rules. My "Add This Rule" button is missing!! 
Specifically, I opened the tool by selecting Asp.Net Configuration from the Website menu dropdown. In the tool, I clicked The Security Tab, then clicked the Create access rules link.
The page opens:
[image: New Access Rule screenshot]

Even if I make changes, the Add This Rule button doesn't appear.
This happens in Chrome and Internet Explorer 8 and 10.
I am able to add users and roles. I can view and access the database using Visual Studio's Server Explorer, and the data is there.

The Add This Rule button should be there and it isn't. I'm stuck.

Thanks for any advice or direction.

System: Windows7Pro, VS2010 V10.0.40219.1SP1Rel, .NET Framework 4.5.50709SP1Rel, all licensed and fresh install about a week ago (just built the computer).

Answer (score 1):

Via your post on the ASP.NET: http://forums.asp.net/t/1937401.aspx?Web+Site+Administration+Tool+Access+Rule+button+missing

> So the answer is if your Add This Rule button is missing, just click the OK button, and the Tool should save your rule.

This actually does work.  I'm not sure why the button is missing, but if you go to `Manage access rules`, the rule does save if you hit OK.